# Azureについて、IoT Hub で受信したメッセージを Functions で処理方法について

Tags: azure

Azure Event Grid を使用して、下記の図の様な流れで処理することが可能でしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

①IoTデバイスからメッセージが送信される。
②メッセージをIoTHubで受信する。
③EventGridがIoTHubをトリガーに、Functionsを呼ぶ。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IoT Hub内部で存在するEvent HubsとAzure FunctionsのEvent Hubsトリガーを使うことで結果的にIoT Hubで受信後Functionsを呼ぶという仕組みを実装できます。

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-iot